# Calculating the number of matches for every sublist separately

Tags: racket, sublist

Here is my big list with sublists:

```
   (define family
      (list
       (list 'Daddy 't-shirt 'raincoat 'sunglasses 'pants 'coat 'sneakers)
       (list 'Mamma 'high-heels 'dress 'pants 'sunglasses 'scarf)
       (list 'son 'pants 'sunglasses 'sneakers 't-shirt 'jacket)
       (list 'daughter 'bikini 'Leggings 'sneakers 'blouse 'top)))
```

And i want to compare `family` with this simple list:

```
   (list 'sneakers 'dress 'pants 'sunglasses 'scarf)
```

each matching should give 1 point and i want that the point to be calculated separately for each sublist.

Here is the code:

;checking if an element exists in a list

```
(define occurs?
  (lambda (element lst)                  
    (cond
      [(and (null? element) (null? lst))] 
      [(null? lst) #f]
      [(pair?  lst)
       (if
        (occurs? element (car lst)) #t
        (occurs? element (cdr lst)))]
      [else (eqv? element lst)])))
;--------------------------------------
```

; a list of just names are created.

```
(define (name-list lst)
  (list (map car lst)))
```

; Each sublist has a name (car of the sublist). The name-list turn to point-list for each sublist. All of my code except the code below is functioning as i want. The problem lies within `point-list` code.

```
(define (point lst db)
  (let ((no-point (name-list db)))
    (cond ((or (null? lst) (null? db)) '())
          (set! (first no-point) (comp lst (rest db)))
          (else (point lst (cdr db))))))
```

Daddy-sublist has 3 elements in common. Mamma-sublist has 4 elements in common, son-sublist 3 elements and daugther-sublist 1 element.

I want the outdata to be like this:

```
> (comparison (list 'sneakers 'dress 'pants 'sunglasses 'scarf) family)
'(3 4 3 1)
```

My code is not functioning as I want it. I get this Eror :

```
set!: bad syntax in: set!
```

Can someone guide explain me what to do?

Comment: what is the actual output for the call `(comparison (list 'sneakers 'dress 'pants 'sunglasses 'scarf) family)`? (this is one of things that go into a well-asked question: the code, the desired and the actual output, ...)

Comment: the output is 1 !! So it's finding just the first element of the family-list. i tried even this code: (define (comparison-help lst1 lst2 res)
  (if (null? lst1) res
      (if (occurs? (car lst1) lst2)         
          (comparison-help (cdr lst1) lst2 (+ 1 res))
          (comparison-help (cdr lst1) lst2 res))))

(define (comparison lst1 lst2)
  (comparison-help lst1 lst2 0))       but the code is running just for the first sub-list. The output for this code is 5

Comment: add this into the question itself! you can edit it. click on "edit" or something.

Comment: I edited some parts of the code. Can you tell me if it is better now? But i get error for bad syntax :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bad syntax with `set!`:

```
          (set! (first no-point-lst) (comparison lst (rest db)))
```

This is an invalid use of `set!`, attempting to *"mutate the structure"* of the list `no-point-lst`, changing what's actually held in its first position.

`set!` can't do that. It can be used to change a binding, i.e. the value of a variable: `(let ((a 1)) (set! a 2))`.

In Common Lisp they can write `(setf (first list) newval)`, but not in Scheme / Racket.

If this is essential to your algorithm, you can use `set-car!` in R5RS Scheme, or `set-mcar!` in Racket. Or you could do this with [vectors](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html).

But you could also restructure your code as

```
        (set! no-points-list 
              (cons 
                 (comparison lst (rest db))
                 (cdr no-points-list)))
```

Comment: But it is erroring bad syntax in set! when i used you suggested code :(

Comment: After 10 hours i could fix my code. Thank you Will Ness.

Comment: that's good news. it's manageable, isn't it, when you ask pointed, focused questions, and work on one problem at a time!